# Display Persian time in format hh:mm

Tags: c#, datetime, calendar, globalization, datetime-format

I am using a persian calender on my application , i am using that code :

```
using System.Globalization;

[...]

PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
DateTime thistime = DateTime.Now;
string persiantimenow = pc.GetHour(thistime) + ":" + pc.GetMinute(thistime);

Console.WriteLine(persiantimenow);
```

It is 12:35AM now , so the output is : 0:33 , but i want it to be 00:33

I tried using :

```
string persiantimenow = pc.GetHour(thistime.ToString("hh")) + ":" + pc.GetMinute(thistime.ToString("mm"));
```

It gave me error so i used the next one , but also gave same error

```
string thistime_Hour = thistime.ToString("HH");
string thistime_minute = thistime.ToString("MM");

string persiantimenow = pc.GetHour(thistime_Hour) + ":" + pc.GetMinut(thistime_minute);
```

But i get Error :

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.DateTime'
```

EDIT 1 [I have figured a tricky solution]

```
if (pc.GetHour(thistime) < 12)
{
     string persiantimenow = "0" + pc.GetHour(thistime) + ":" + pc.GetMinute(thistime);
     Console.WriteLine(persiantimenow);
}
```

It is not what i needed but it solves the issue.

EDIT 2 [L.B solved it for me]
Here is the solution :

```
string persiantimenow = pc.GetHour(thistime).ToString("00") + ":" + pc.GetMinute(thistime).ToString("00");
```

Comment: Where is the PersianCalender code? We can't test ideas if we cant test the code.

Comment: You need to import :using System.Globalization;

Comment: `string persiantimenow = pc.GetHour(thistime).ToString("00") + ":" + pc.GetMinute(thistime).ToString("00")`

Comment: Nice one @L.B , i didn`t know that i can place 0`s , Thank you very much for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you'd use a [`DateTimeFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) which has the `Calendar` property set to be the `PersianCalendar`. However, from the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar.aspx):

> Your application should not use a PersianCalendar object as the default calendar for a culture. The default calendar is specified by the CultureInfo.Calendar property and must be one of the calendars returned by the CultureInfo.OptionalCalendars property. Currently, the PersianCalendar class is not an optional calendar for any culture supported by the CultureInfo class and consequently cannot be a default calendar.

That makes it hard to use without fudging it, basically :(

For the hour/minute though, does the calendar actually matter? I'm very aware that different calendars treat different *dates* differently, but do they treat *times* differently? Can you not just use the invariant culture, for time fields?

Comment: The answer to the question "For the hour/minute though, does the calendar actually matter?" is yes. For instance, not all calendars share the same start-of-day: in the Islamic, Baha'i and Hebrew calendars, the day starts at sunset; in the Hebrew calendar, the day starts at sunset. See the most excellent book _Calendrical Calculations_ for a fascinating and informative look at calendars and calendar math. http://www.amazon.com/Calendrical-Calculations-Nachum-Dershowitz/dp/0521702380/

Comment: @NicholasCarey: Yes, I've got that already - but I thought that although observational calendars were used by religious organizations, for most modern business and political uses, the more predictable "days start at midnight" time was generally used.

Comment: @NicholasCarey: (In particular, using the `PersianCalendar` class on my box at the moment doesn't seem to affect the time... but it *does* affect the date.)

Answer (score 0):

```
 time.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        time.Text = time.Text.Replace("AM", "صبح");
        time.Text = time.Text.Replace("PM", "عصر");
```